# How to use for loop to sum all the stocks price after multiply by their own respective number of units?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I want to find the total sum of all the stocks in `sym` after multiply by their own respective `units`. Which means the end result for the `total` should have 6 columns. Based on the example in the code:

After loading the stock price for all the stocks in `sym`, which is `SBUX`, `V`, `MA`, `GOOGL` and `MSFT`, I want the `for loop` can do the task as shown below for me:

```
Total = SBUX*units[1] + V*units[2] + MA*units[3] + GOOGL*units[4] + MSFT*units[5]
```

Each stocks will have their own `Open, High, Low, Close, Adjusted, Volume` respectively, and hence after mutiply by their repective units and sum them up, the `total` should have `Open, High, Low, Close, Adjusted, Volume`as well.

I attached a diagram below as the final output that I want (I'm using different stocks and units in the diagram below compare to the example in my code, so the results are different). Basically the number in the table should be big since it is the sum of all the stocks after multiply by their own units.

I'm only able to multiply the stock with their own `units` but have no idea on how to sum them up.

[image]

```
library(quantmod)

sym = c("SBUX","V","MA","GOOGL","MSFT")
l=length(sym)
units <- c(2,4,6,2,8)

total <- c()
for (i in 1:l){
  total = getSymbols(sym[i], src="yahoo", from="2014-07-01", periodicity = "weekly" ,auto.assign = F)*units[i]
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'sum them up'?

Comment: Hi Manuel, I have edit the question already, hope it is clearer for you now, please let me know if you still don't get what I mean. Thanks:)

Comment: Would the final output have only 6 columns ? where first column would be `SBUX.Open + V.Open + MA.Open + GOOGL.Open +  MSFT.Open` after multiplying by their `units`  ?

Comment: Ya, only 6 column if you didn't consider the date in front as column 1, actually is just the same as the diagram I attached. You are right for the first column, so the second coumn will be `SBUX.High + V.High + MA.High + GOOGL.High + MSFT.High` after multiplying by their units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need  a list to hold all the symbols

```
library(quantmod)

total <- vector("list", length(sym))
for (i in 1:l) {
   total[[i]] = getSymbols(sym[i], src="yahoo", from="2014-07-01", 
                periodicity = "weekly" ,auto.assign = F)*units[i]
}
```

Since the period is the same for all the symbols, we can use directly add them element-wise

```
output <- Reduce(`+`, total)

head(output)

#           SBUX.Open SBUX.High  SBUX.Low SBUX.Close SBUX.Volume SBUX.Adjusted
#2014-06-30   2237.08 2283.9800 2222.7599  2276.5700  1058484400     2205.1217
#2014-07-07   2274.87 2285.3100 2211.9199  2260.6001  1274115600     2189.0978
#2014-07-14   2275.33 2358.3000 2240.9499  2330.8800  2386777200     2257.2618
#2014-07-21   2319.23 2356.2500 2282.4900  2300.1700  2018956800     2227.2952
#2014-07-28   2297.80 2312.8999 2209.6000  2228.7500  1709671400     2157.7895
#2014-08-04   2239.23 2261.4300 2199.5600  2240.5800  1536708200     2169.2998
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! Thats what I am looking for. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be solved with one `lapply` loop over the list `total`. I have also read the data in with a `lapply` loop because I find it more idiomatic.

```
library(quantmod)

sym <- c("SBUX", "V", "MA", "GOOGL", "MSFT")
units <- c(2, 4, 6, 2, 8)

total <- lapply(sym, function(s){
  getSymbols(s, 
             src = "yahoo", 
             from = "2014-07-01", 
             periodicity = "weekly", 
             auto.assign = FALSE)

})
names(total) <- sym

total <- lapply(seq_along(total), function(i) total[[i]]*units[i])
```

Now see the first 6 rows of the first `xts` object.

```
head(total$SBUX)
#           SBUX.Open SBUX.High SBUX.Low SBUX.Close SBUX.Volume SBUX.Adjusted
#2014-06-30     78.10     79.40    77.08      79.06    58238400      72.25039
#2014-07-07     78.78     79.48    78.14      78.60    63975200      71.83001
#2014-07-14     78.98     79.15    77.12      77.94    73348000      71.22685
#2014-07-21     77.86     80.64    77.17      78.74   106043200      71.95795
#2014-07-28     78.80     79.25    76.58      76.98    81607600      70.34956
#2014-08-04     77.26     77.76    76.27      77.62    60595200      70.93442
```

To add up all tables can be done with something like this:

```
result <- total[[1]]
for(i in seq_along(total)[-1]) result <- result + total[[i]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, after I run the final line of the code, the `total` show 5 group of tables such that each table represent each stock, but what I want is the sum of all the 5 tables. What can I do next?

Comment: @SiewHunWong Done, see at the end.